# Python predicate function name convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions, predicate

Does Python have some convention for names of predicate functions? For example predicate function names end with `p` for Common Lisp or `?` for Scheme. Sometimes are used prefixes like `is_` or `has_`, ..., but they may not be appropriate in some cases (they can be quite long to make sense and does not have to be obvious that function is predicate at first sight).

Comment: Python style conventions are provided in [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which doesn't cover predicate functions specifically.

Comment: If you take the standard library as a role model, then `ispredicate` or `haspredicate` is standard. For example, the standard library has `isinstance`, `issubclass`, and `hasattr` predicates.

Comment: Also, `str.isupper`, `str.islower`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Python has no such official convention. Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for what *is* standardized in Python.

In Python, *readability counts*. If something is a predicate function, anyone should be able to immediately tell what that function is without knowing any of your standards. `isinstance`, `str.isupper`, `hasattr` are all part of the standard library, which is a good indication of the canonical style. I can immediately tell what these functions do and return without even reading the documentation. Go with whatever you think is the most readable to someone unfamiliar with your code, which will most likely be `is` or `has` prefixes.